# How to pass an object of points from js to java as a list?

Tags: javascript, java

I have a method in sample class java:

```
public doThis(List<Point> points) {
 for(Point apoint: points) {
    some code here...
 }
}
```

and I called this to my js using an object of points

```
var points = [{x:-676, y:69}, {x:-196, y:69}, {x:281, y:69}];
sample.doThis(points);
```

since its an object, its not getting accepted as a list.

How do I convert the js object to a list?

Help are much appreciated!

Comment: I'm guessing you meant JSON and not JavaScript, right? And you are asking how to parse a JSON string into a List of coordinates? If that's the case, please edit your question, its misleading.

Comment: You cannot "call" a method in java from javascript. These are 2 completely different languages. You can write 2 different applications, one in java and the other in js, and have them communicate using some cross-language protocol, such as REST or SOAP. In this case, the protocol defines the conversion from the in-language representation to the protocol's representation, and vice versa.